# why can I only see the pages and websites that I liked using Grap API on facebook but not specifics such as the videos that I liked?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is a page that I liked:

```
"category": 
"Professional sports team", 
      "name": 
"MMA Academy Lebanon", 
      "created_time": 
"2014-02-27T08:26:50+0000", 
      "id": 
"145482752217243"
    },
```

However if I like a video in this page, for example, it will not show even though it is a node and supposedly has an ID.
I red all of what is in the graph api guide but could not find my answer. Could you please help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `like` connection of the `User` object does only return Page likes! To receive the object likes (and a video is an object), you need to use the FQL table `like` in a FQL statement as follows:

```
select user_id, object_id, object_type from like where user_id=me()
```